# UK transit with USA residence card initially issued before 21 April 1998

Tags: uk, transit-visas

Reading transit visa requirements in UK, it says I need "**USA Permanent Residence card issued by the USA on or after 21 April 1998**". I initially got my Green Card in 1995, and renewed it twice since then. My current card was renewed (also meaning I received a new physical card) just a few years ago. But the card has only two dates -- when I initially became resident in 1995, and the expiration date (a few years from today). There's no date on when this renewed physical card was "printed"/when it was renewed.

Can I transit UK with this green card w/o getting a transit visa? Is it considered "issued after 21 April 1998"? If so, how will they know?

Also, what's with this date - 21 April 1998 -- what happened then? Some law came into effect? US-UK integration established?

Comment: Maybe it has to do with machine readability ?

Comment: maybe, but I'd love to get someone's experience on this, ok more concrete knowledge, before I spend hundreds of $ on tix :( gov.uk has paid visa support. I paid ~5 eur and asked this question. their reply: "contact an immigration advisor"

Comment: Green cards that have an expiration date, have an expiration date that is no more than 10 years after issue. So from the expiration date, one can infer that your green card was issued after 1998.

Comment: @flamey they're talking about the physical card you present, not your status.

Comment: @user102008 but is that information available to the ground agent who is considering whether to issue a boarding pass to flamey for a flight to the UK?  Does TIMATIC say that a green card meets the legal requirement if it has an expiration date?

Comment: @user102008 that's _exactly_ what's confusing me. there's no card issue date on the card! _I_ know the date, because I can login to my USCIS account and see when they sent me the card. But how will _they_ know in UK? But I _guess_ they do know just by the looks of the card, it's features.. Also, I just noticed a tiny-tiny test on the back: `Form I-551, Rev 02-2016`, which, I guess, means the revision of the physical card format. Still not the "Issued on..."! Anyways, I'm pretty confident now that I should be ok.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The US started to issue only green cards with enhanced security features, such as digital printing, optical stripe and holograms, in April 1998. Machine-readability had been introduced on previous versions, but counterfeits were a problem.

The new format then also introduced the name "Permanent Resident Card", instead of writing "alien" or "resident alien". **That is, if your card has the words "permanent resident" on it, it is issued after April 21, 1998.**

https://www.aila.org/library/ins-green-card-questions--answers (INS announcement dated April 21, 1998; archived by the American Immigration Lawyers Association)

Comment: Inferring the connection between your answer and the question, is it correct to say the transit requirement is "USA Permanent Residence card with security features; said features being included in cards issued on or after 21 April 1998" ?

Comment: The actual physical card presented must be issued after that date. That's what the OP is asking and the answer doesn't explicitly say

Comment: @BenVoigt that night be a better way of expressing the requirement, but it's not how the requirement is actually expressed.